# Unexpected has occurred

Tags: sharepoint-designer

An Unexpected error has occurred on my sites .When i try to View All my pages in my site it generates this error "Error 
An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 0541cbd4-548c-4788-a23e-bb4d3482efa7

Date and Time: 10/20/2012 10:31:00 PM 
"

Comment: Umar, you can use [SharePoint LogViewer](http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/) to identify the error behind this correlation... Just open the lastest LOG file in this viewer and search for the correlation!

Answer (score 1):

Go to this path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Open the LOG file (NOT .usage file) and find the error message with Correlation ID.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is in a production environment, you can use the ULS Log Viewer to analyze the SharePoint Logs. To identify the error, you can use the Correlation ID as a filter or by grouping values as a treeview. Here's the link for ULS Viewer:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

If the error is happening on a development environment, you can enable stack trace to show on the page. This will simply show the error in the page, making debugging easier.

For this, you need to go to the virtual folder of your web application, and modify the web.config file like this to turn off CustomErrors and enable CallStack and AllowPageLevelTrace. You need to do this for each web application that you want to show errors in the page.

Under <system.web>

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Under <SharePoint> tag

```
<SafeMode CallStack="true" AllowPageLevelTrace="true">
```